# Can I start downloading the blockchain, power off the computer, and restart later?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, raspberry-pi

- I have an RPi 3b, the OS is set up and internet works.
- I'm a programmer, know how to use basic linux (but I'm not great at being a linux admin), but I'm new to RPi and setting up a cryptocurrency node.
- I plan to use geth to set up a ETH node. I'm not mining yet. An RPi does not seem to be great for mining.
- I also have a 32GB SDCard and 1TB USB external drive. I have yet to set up the drive for RPi.
- Internet speed will be at least 35mbps over wifi for the RPi 3b. Thank goodness for 4 USB ports on that thing!

I'll be changing my ISP on Saturday. Can I start downloading the blockchain today (Wed), power off the RPi, and continue downloading the blockchain after I get my new ISP and modem/router?

Thank you! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to restart your sync.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you are syncing.

If you do the full sync, then you can restart but it can take a huge time.
If you do a fast-sync, you are not syncing the full blockchain,
but only the state at some point. It cannot be stoped but it is faster.

I think in your case, the best solution is the third way: light-sync.
It does not download the entire blockchain, but only relevant information
for your use case. Thus, it is impossible to mine with a light-synced blockchain.

Comment: You don't need a client at all to mine

Comment: @TjadenHess : I don't get your comment. At least, you need to get the blockchain, don't you ?

Comment: No, you can pool mine without actually having the blockchain locally. You just need block header candidates

Comment: @TjadenHess: Well, what I meant is simply that miner.start does not work on a light synced geth.

Comment: A light-sync might work since I don't want to mine (yet), I just want to be a node. Mining would come later after I get the node running.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do all at once. Because after downloading the blockchain, your machine will start validating states and it can´t be stopped. If you stop, you have to start from zero.

Comment: So, if the power goes out, I have to download the whole blockchain again? That sounds like it could take 7+ days each time.

Comment: I've used ethereumj (java implementation) and you can stop the node in mid sync. On restart it will pick up where it left off.

Comment: Which is why people recommend a UPS? So Linux doesn't crash from a power outage and we don't have to download the blockchain again?